# To store jwt token undecoded server-side or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, token, jwt

Forgive me if this is a stupid question.

As the title asks, is it not expensive to decode the token server-side for each request, would it not be better to store and look up the undecoded token? 
Would you store session tokens in nodejs object or mongodb? 
Mongodb would be another round trip but then you can use _id to find easily.(please correct me if i'm wrong, I'm learning as i go so advise/resources = very welcome!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It depends**

Just validating the signature means that make sure that the token was generated with your secret key.

Storing and checking the tokens means that you can validate that the token is created by your server. This way you can also invalidate individual tokens, e.g. if a user lost his/her phone s/he can invalidate the one.

Key-value databases, such as Redis, are usually used for this kind of storage as they perform *very* well for these simple put/get operations and will give you several hundred thousands operations per second.

Comment: thanks for the reply , this helps a lot already, so client-side i would store JWT and username in cooky right; it doesn't get decoded client-side right?

Comment: You may store a JWT in a Cookie if you want to (see https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/ ) The username is usually a part of the signed payload. You want to store the username in the JWT itself, example: http://jwt.io/ And no, usually you don't decode it client side, BUT: don't have any secrets in the JWT as the user can view all the content. See the previous link.

Comment: Thanks For the Extra Info! :)

Answer (score 1):

And where is it stored now? If in the cookie you don't need to store it somewhere else in the decoded form. Access to any external storage like mongo will always be more expensive than decode something from base64 or json.

Meanwhile, if it doesn't stored at all (and used only to obtain an access), you must not to store it wherever, because the JWT token is like a password. You have to avoid storing such things in your DBs.